# Table not inheriting width

Tags: html, css, netsuite

I'm having an issue getting my body content to scale properly.

It will open to 100% when the page is opened and if you re-size the screen wider it gets bigger but if you go smaller it stays at whatever the widest you stretched it to was.

Netsuite uses an insane amount of tables to structure things which I think may be causing the problem. Here is the link to my sandbox site:

http://shopping.sandbox.netsuite.com/s.nl?c=3573268

We just started development so forgive the mess.

I notice that when I check it in Chrome's dev tools it tells me that the body content div scales with the screen but the table that resides just inside it is what is sticking to the max width.

How do I get this table to inherit the width of the body div?

Comment: it looks at first glance that there is some JS that is dynamically setting min-width on an element. Have you tried looking in the JS?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the only JS that I added was for the Flexslider2 which is natively set up to fill the available space of the parent to 100% of the width. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ Is there a reason that would cause a parent table to stick to the widest width?

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing right now. `table-layout: fixed` solves the problem, but for some reason prevents a `transition` on the parent node's sibling ... fml ...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I had to assign the following properties to the containing div that lies within all the tables:

```
.mainContents {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
}
```

I couldn't tell you the logic behind why it works, but it works. I tried about a thousand other things that would have made more sense but what ever...